# KDB rolling sum

Tags: kdb

I have a table

```
t:flip `date`sym`ts`qty!(`d1`d1`d1`d1`d1`d1`d2;`s1`s1`s2`s1`s1`s2`s1;`t1`t1`t2`t3`t4`t5`t1;-100 -100 200 200 500 -300 -400)

date    sym   ts     qty
d1       s1   t1    -100
d1       s1   t1    -100
d1       s2   t2     200
d1       s1   t3     200
d1       s1   t4     500
d1       s2   t5    -300
d2       s1   t1    -400
```

and I would like to get the cummulative sum of qty for each sym up to that moment for the same day

```
date    sym   ts     qty   cumsum
d1       s1   t1    -100     -200 // -100 - 100
d1       s2   t2     200      200 //  200
d1       s1   t3     200        0 // -100 -100 + 200
d1       s1   t4     500      500 // -100 -100 + 200 + 500
d1       s2   t5    -300     -100 //  200 - 300
d2       s1   t1    -400     -400 // -400 (date is d2)
```

I tried using

```
select sums qty by date, ts, sym from t
```

but with this I only managed to collapse rows that have the same key `date`ts`sym into a list, but it doesnt give me a rolling sum. any suggestions?

EDIT:
so, basically I want to append a column that shows the value I would get from this query

```
select sum qty from t where sym =`symbol_of_this_row, ts <= ts_of_this_row, date = _date_of_this_row
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
//Ascend by date and time to make sure that result sets match
`date`ts xasc 
    //Compute cumulative sums by date, sym, timestamp
    update sums cumul by date,sym from 
        //Make sure that there is a single qty for each timestamp
        select cumul:sum qty by date,sym,ts from t
```

Answer (score 1):

i may be misunderstanding your question.. so you want the cumulative sum for the rows that match `date`sym`timestamp, yeah?

How about this:

```
    t: update cumsum:sums qty by date, sym, ts from t
    // for the sake of 'pretty view' sort by `date`sym`ts 
    `date`sym`ts xasc t
```

EDIT: I'm sure you can make it prettier by doing functional update (http://www.timestored.com/kdb-guides/functional-queries-dynamic-sql)
I just wrote some function on my own to show you the basic idea.
1. Pass table and each row of table.

```
    temp:{[idx; tbl]
         row: first select from tbl where i = idx;
         : last update cumulative:sums qty from (select from tbl where date=row[`date], sym=row[`sym], ts<=row[`ts]);
         };
```

2. update the table via each right (/)

   ```
    temp2:{[tbl; idx]
       row: first select from tbl where i = idx;
       :tbl lj (`date`sym`ts xkey enlist last update cumulative:sums qty from  (select from tbl where date=row[`date],sym=row[`sym],ts<=row[`ts]));
       };
   ```

for #1, you can call something like:

```
tbl: {: temp[y; x] }[; tbl] each til count tbl
```

for #2, you can call something like:

```
tbl: temp2/[tbl; til count tbl]
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work, although a little ugly;

```
`date`ts xasc 0! / sort and unkey
    update cumsum:sums qty by date, sym from 
        select sum qty by date, sym, ts from t
```

Which produces;

```
date sym ts qty  cumsum
-----------------------
d1   s1  t1 -200 -200  
d1   s2  t2 200  200   
d1   s1  t3 200  0     
d1   s1  t4 500  500   
d1   s2  t5 -300 -100  
d2   s1  t1 -400 -400
```

Notice qty in the first row is different to your example. That is because I had to aggregate the data within the same ts before running the cumulative sum. There is probably a way to do this implicitly but it won't come to me right now.

Answer (score 0):

If the rows are in chronological order, there is no need to sort the table: the *by* clause will do what you want.

1. Use `update` to calculate `cumsum` by `date` and `ts`
2. Select **`last`** value of `cumsum` by `date`, `ts`, and `sym`
3. Remove key

```
q)0!select last cumsum by date,ts,sym from update cumsum: sums qty by date,sym from t
date ts sym cumsum
------------------
d1   t1 s1  -200
d1   t2 s2  200
d1   t3 s1  0
d1   t4 s1  500
d1   t5 s2  -100
d2   t1 s1  -400
```

If you need to *parameterise* any of this (i.e. pass column names as arguments) you will want the [functional forms](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/funsql):

```
q)u:![t;();`date`sym!`date`sym;(enlist`cumsum)!enlist(sums;`qty)]
q)0!?[u;();`date`ts`sym!`date`ts`sym;(enlist`cumsum)!enlist(last;`cumsum)]
```

More at [*Q for Mortals*: §9. Queries](http://code.kx.com/q4m3/9_Queries_q-sql/)